# How design layout to support multiple screen and resolution in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design layouts which will support multiple screen and resulution,the normal hdpi layout is okay but the other layout like large mdpi is not displaying as expected.Here are  the samples

Normal Hdpi

[image: Normal HDPI]

[image: Large MDPI]

Large Mdpi

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for it:-

1)use DisplayMetrics

2) Making different layout files

if you going for using 2nd way then refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I have already putted these files to the res/layout and res/layout-large folder,I want to know about the button background image,how to design the images for multiple screen.

Comment: for that just declare all the dimensions in dimens file and for different layout just change the dimensions in proper file

Comment: I have done that also but the images are displaying small or large,I am little bit confused about designing drawables for different density.

Comment: for example : Suppose you have one ImageView in xml and you set layout_width="@dimen/img_width" after this you have to change img_width in all dimens files.

Answer (score 0):

read this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

put your drawables accordingly in ldpi, hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi folders.

read this as well for design guidelines:
http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it seems like you want a background image for different densities.
You can achieve that from eclipse like this

Press ctrl+N(File-->New-->Others) ---> android---> android icon set-->Choose your preferecnce, provide the name & press next--->under foreground tab, press image---> provide url of an image----> press finish.

This will automatically create an image of different densities in your different folders.

Or if you dont want to use eclipse then,
http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

this link will serve the same purpose.